# C#. Экранирование спецсимволов в строке для SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Есть ли стандартные функции экранирования строк для SQL запроса? Я имею в виду вместо добавления в `SqlCommand` параметров, может можно безопасно вставлять необходимые мне значения прямо в текст SQL запроса? Мне в любом случае необходимо объединять строки для вставки значений вроде "@p1, @p2" и так далее. Мне кажется если вставлять данные напрямую программа будет работать быстрее, но без экранирования может быть sql injection.

Comment: можно использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: @RasulHuseynov можете привести пример?

Comment: Ну так вы попробуйте, быстрее ли. И на сколько. Ну и не забывайте, про кэширование плана запроса

Comment: что надо первом случае определись Для чего надо для пользователей программы или программистов как фреймворк.

многим случай используются регулярные выражения вам надо контролировать ники и символы которые для 'Sql Injection' .Ну в другом случае можно это структурировать на объектно-ориентированное то есть там не будет прямая стоковая информация.

для asp.net маленький пример.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: ни в коем случае не собирайте sql вручную. быстрее не будет. надежного способа экранирования нет. передавайте параметры параметрами.

Comment: @RasulHuseynov это гайд 2005-го года, и даже в нем прямо сказано - Use type-safe SQL parameters for data access

Comment: О, я обязан [оставить это здесь](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В SQL Server есть кэш планов. При выполнении каждого запроса SQL Server смотрит, есть ли уже существующий план в кэше, и если есть - экономит время за счет переиспользования плана.

Поиск в кэше осуществляется по тексту запроса. [Значения параметров в текст запроса не входят](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186219(v=sql.105).aspx).

Если вы пришлете запрос с другим текстом - SQL Server вынужден будет построить план заново. Построение плана - дорогая операция. Иногда она даже дороже, чем само выполнение запроса.

Вот такие запросы, со значением прямо в тексте, потребуют двух компиляций запроса в план:

```
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = 1;

SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = 4;
```

Если вы пришлете запрос с тем же текстом, но другими значениями параметров - SQL Server использует существующий план, что гораздо быстрее:

```
-- первое выполнение вызовет построение плана
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = @ProductSubcategoryID;

-- используется существующий план, вне зависимости от значения @ProductSubcategoryID
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product 
WHERE ProductSubcategoryID = @ProductSubcategoryID;
```

Т.е. то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - вставлять значения прямо в текст запроса - не ускорит, а наоборот, замедлит выполнение. Не говоря уже о проблемах с безопасностью, которые вы при этом получите.

Причем производительность падает настолько, что в SQL Server 2005 добавили режим [FORCED параметризации](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037(v=sql.105).aspx), который принудительно делает из непараметризированных запросов параметризированные - т.е. MS очень старательно пытается заставить вас использовать параметры ради производительности. Вплоть до [графиков в SQL Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-advisor), где рисуется нагрузка вашей базы, и нагрузка "вот такой она могла бы быть при использовании параметров".

Comment: _"в последнем SQL Server добавили режим FORCED"_, точнее - в SqlServer 2005.

Comment: @i-one кажется я совсем старый стал. спасибо, уточнил :)

Answer (score 2):

Наоборот, запросы с параметрами будут работать быстрее, поскольку БД запоминает их и постепенно оптимизирует. А в случае цельного запроса, она будет считать каждый запрос новым и от аналогичных запросов ничего оставаться не будет.

Comment: с автоматической параметризацией это не совсем так - будет работать с той же скоростью

Comment: @PashaPash, не в курсе про неё.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175037(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Минусатор, прокомментируй.